# How to avoid warning PE1053 when casting a 64-bit value to a 32-bit pointer in C?

Tags: c, warnings

I'd like to support 32-Bit and 64-Bit Version of my code.
My architecture has a static non volatile memory, where I can store data. But the variable size is static, so I change it. So I use a 64 Bit variable to store a address pointer. This works for 32 bit & 64 bit.

I store in the initialization phase a address to a 64-Bit variable (u64 prefix means unsigned int 64 bit variable).

**Init**

```
extern MEMORY tNonVolatileMemory;
MY_TYPE tType;

// Can be 32 bit in 32 Bit version
tNonVolatileMemory.u64Address = &tType;
```

When I'd like to re-use the address there occures a Compiler error:

*Warning[Pe1053]: conversion from integer to smaller pointer*

**Runtime**

```
extern MEMORY tNonVolatileMemory;
MY_TYPE* ptType; 

ptType = (MY_TYPE*)tNonVolatileMemory.u64Address;
```

Is there any programming methodes to avoid this warning?

I tried to cast fist to a void pointer to avoid the compiler warning

Comment: This warning is specific to a compiler. The compiler probably has a way to suppress it. You didn't tell us  which compiler you are using.

Comment: In any case, you better change the type (and name) of `u64Address` to something that will be architecture specific. Either make it a pointer type or an integer that is designed to hold a pointer value, such as `uintptr_t`

Comment: If you do not want to change the type of `u64Address`, cast it to `uintptr_t` before casting to a pointer: `ptType = (MY_TYPE *) (uintptr_t) tNonVolatileMemory.u64Address;`.

Comment: `stdint.h` is the key to portable code. All your integers ought to be the fixed width ones from that library. To solve the pointer issue, you should use `uintptr_t` when storing pointer addresses in integer format. This is a portable type guaranteed to be large enough to fit a pointer on the given system. As for how to fix your code, you have to post the struct/type definitions.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're converting to and from an integer type in the first place?  Why not just store a pointer?

Answer (score 3):

> How to avoid warning PE1053 when casting a 64-bit value to a 32-bit pointer in C?
> "I use a 64 Bit variable to store a address pointer"

Instead of casting, use a pointer variable to store a pointer.

```
extern void *tNonVolatileMemory;

tNonVolatileMemory = &tType;
```

---

If wanting that variable to always take up the same space on 32-address machines versus 64-bit address machines, then use a `union`.

```
_Static_assert(sizeof (void *) <= sizeof(uint64_t), "Pointer too large");
union {
  void *ptr;
  uint64_t u64;
} tNonVolatileMemory;

tNonVolatileMemory.ptr = &tType;
```